# Limiting the range of values allowed in multiple textboxes

Tags: vb.net

For my current assignment, I've been asked to create a form to allow customers to enter desired quantities of shoes in a textbox and then total the cost in a second textbox. However, the customer cannot purchase more than 3 of any one particular shoe. I attempted to do the first two shoes in the code below but am running into issues once I added the code for the second model.

```
    Private Sub btnCompute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCompute.Click
        Dim qntyClassy, qntyHigh As Double
        txtQntyClassy.Text = qntyClassy
        txtQntyHigh.Text = qntyHigh
        If 0 < Int(txtQntyClassy.Text) And Int(txtQntyClassy.Text) < 4 Then
            txtTotalClassy.Text = FormatCurrency(txtQntyClassy.Text * 43)
            txtQntyClassy.Text = Int(txtQntyClassy.Text)
        Else
            MsgBox("Enter a quantity no greater than 3.")
        End If
        If 0 < Int(txtQntyHigh.Text) And Int(txtQntyHigh.Text) < 4 Then
            txtTotalHigh.Text = FormatCurrency(txtQntyHigh.Text * 48.95)
            txtQntyHigh.Text = Int(txtQntyHigh.Text)
        Else
            MsgBox("Enter a quantity no greater than 3.")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What's the issue then? You haven't asked a question, given an error or expected vs actual behaviour, etc.

Comment: Get stuck into the Validate method and parse all your textboxes each time.

Comment: I'm assuming you HAVE to use a TextBox, but if you don't, I'd use a NumericUpDown for something like this... It's a lot easier to code and a lot friendlier for the user.